# Xcode is missing some header files

Tags: c++, xcode

I need access to:

```
#include <vector>        // to form variable length arrays
#include <algorithm>    // For max()
```

Any ideas.  This is a C++ cmd line tool written as an Xcode 4.2.1 project.  So the file is main.cpp.

Comment: We need a lot more information than this. What exactly are you doing (what is the file called, how did you create the project, why do you think that the compiler is ignoring your `#include`s)?

Comment: #include <algorithm>    // For max() should allow me to use the max() operator.  It does not.  Nor does the <vector> do anything.  I am working on a cmd line tool in C++

Comment: So, in short I would like write a C++ progrmam that can call the <algorithm> header file and make use of the max() operator.  I would also like to declare arrays with variables (for varying size Monte Carlo simulations).  I am restricted to the C++ libraries…

Comment: Do you get error messages from the include statements? Or any other error messages?  Do you have `using namespace std;` in your source or do you use `std::max` and `std::vector`?

Comment: No, because that did not fix the problem.  Using: "using namespace std" give me the IDE red flag of "no matching function for call max," while if I leave it out I get "use of undeclared identifier 'max': do you mean fmax?."  I the latter case Xcode crashes when I click on the flag and bring up this txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got those files right here:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/algorithm
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector
```

If you have the same files in a similar location, it's likely that something is configured incorrectly in your project. Try making a little test project that includes those files. Use the C++ command line template. It'll take you about 90 seconds.

Comment: @Jerome: What was the problem?

Comment: I had been misled on how to use max();  Aside from that I was not told it does not like doubles I did not know I had to use "namespace std."  I was following instructions that did not work well.  That's what I get for not following my instincts when I code.  As it turned out I did not need vectors, or max(), I just wrote work-arounds…